# Why is my form going to background on DragDrop?

Tags: c#, winforms, drag-and-drop, z-order

At the end of a drag&drop operation, I'm showing a form using `ShowDialog`.
**Problem:** When the form is closed, my main form is pushed behind any other application windows.

Code:

```
private void ctrl_DragDrop(object sender, DragEventArgs e) {
    // ...
    if (e.Effect == DragDropEffects.Move) {
    string name = e.Data.GetData(DataFormats.Text).ToString();
    viewHelperForm.ShowDialog(view.TopLevelControl);
    // ...
}
```

**Question: What can I do that the main form stays on top?**

Comment: When the opened form is closed, are any events being fired on the main form?

Comment: do you catch the showDialog? like event a = newWindow.ShowDialog();

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your ShowDialog() call is *blocking* the DragDrop event.  That is very, very bad, it gums up the drag source and make it go catatonic and unresponsive to Windows messages.  This has all kinds of side-effects, like *your* window going catatonic as well or not getting reactivated since the D+D operation isn't completed yet.

Avoid this by only displaying the dialog *after* the D+D operation is completed.  Elegantly done by taking advantage of the Winforms plumbing that allows posting a message to the message queue and get it processed later.  Like this:

```
    private void ctl_DragDrop(object sender, DragEventArgs e) {
        //...
        this.BeginInvoke(new Action(() => {
            viewHelperForm.ShowDialog(view.TopLevelControl);
        }));
    }
```